# How to fix"No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@integer/google_play_services_version)" in Xamarin android c#

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

I inserted these line in AndroidManifest.xml for google map, but am getting this  error:

> "No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value
>   '@integer/google_play_services_version)"

How can I solve this?

Comment: Add 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2' in gradle

Comment: xamarin doesn't uses gradle to build app

Comment: Thanks for your  reply, then how i can solve this,.. pls suggest any solution

Answer (score 0):

Basically this means that the key for `google_play_services_version` is missing from the auto generated Resources.designer.cs file. This should be added to the manifest by the Google Play Services (GPS) library when install the GPS package and build the project. Have you installed the Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps package?

Comment: yeah i installed but am getting error like "package com.google.android.gms.maps.model does not exist"..