# Xamarin.Forms : No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@integer/google_play_services_version')

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am developing an application via Xamarin in Visual Studio and at my first try, I encountered the following errors :

No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@integer/google_play_services_version').

OR

Please install package: 'GPS Base' available in SDK installer.

Which were asked a lot in the Stack Overflow and even in the Xamarin Forum. For example the following links :

[How to fix "No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@integer/google_play_services_version')"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38156985/how-to-fix-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-at-value-with-value)

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/47224/no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-with-value-integer-google-play-services-version

[How to fix"No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@integer/google_play_services_version)" in Xamarin android c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41235047/how-to-fixno-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-at-value-with-value)

BUT nobody has a reliable and correct answer to it.

Is there anybody who can help me to tackle this error please ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: It should automatically be added to your manifest at build time. Which NuGet or Components did you install in your project?

Comment: Nothing, I just tried to build the template project which is created by the wizard when you want to create a new project

Comment: Check the packages that come with the template

Comment: @Cheesebaron : It is not that easy dude ! Check out the link that I put above from Xamarin Forum and you can see it is an issue that most developers are experiencing. If you have time, we can set a time and you can connect to my PC via TeamViewer and see what is going on here ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I do not have the mentioned problems anymore when I removed Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 and installed a fresh version of Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise Edition. It seems that the newly released version of Visual Studio is smart enough to find and manage all those packages for me !

Answer (score 0):

based on the message:

> Please install package: 'GPS Base' available in SDK installer.

I would suggest making sure you have Google Play Services installed in your Android SDK Manager. In VS Tools->Android->Android SDK Manager will open the Android SDK Manager. Scroll down to the "Extras" section and look for Google Play Services and make sure it is installed. In fact I would make sure all of the Google Play XXX packages are installed along with the Google Repository.

Comment: Hi jgoldberger, I installed all the packages available in the Extras Section of the SDK Manager but it still has the same error. If you look at this link : https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/47224/no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-with-value-integer-google-play-services-version , You can see that the source of this error is still unknown.

Comment: Some other errors that appears in the error list are : No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimaryDark'. OR No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar'. :-|

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing same issue. Even after trying so many answers from numerous blogs, none worked. I was able to resolve this by installing Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps nuget package by right clicking on Android project of Xamarin solution and installing the package by selecting Manage NuGet Packages. Earlier I was installing the package using Tools> NuGet Package Manager > Manage NuGet packages for solution. Hope this helps!!